# Delete current job in the Queue Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, beanstalkd

So i have a system to send data through **CURL** according to some configurations set in the **Database**, i'm using **Queues** as i'm afraid of the load it might put on the server as i'm starting the service once *every minute*. This is done as the data must be sent as it comes in, and i don't know when it'll come in, the idea is that it runs *almost* like a **Daemon**.

The problem is, after i get to the Queued job, i need to check if there are any records to send, and if there are none then i need to **skip** that Queued Job, not mark it as failed or anything, just skip it altogether and let the **Listener** move onto the next one, how can this be achieved in Laravel 5.2+?

Is my solution somehow flawed? Would you use anything other than **Queues** for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just returning true on the class that handles the job, without performing any actions should do this.